# Type: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException build in Unity 3D for Windows Store Apps

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine

I am making a build in Unity 3D for Windows Store Apps, but encountered an Unhandled Exception. I haven't experienced such an exception earlier till date.

When running my game, I get a lot(!) of entries in the UnityPlayer.log like this:

```
Exception: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Type: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Module: mscorlib
InnerException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AdditionalInfo:Invoking System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext method with argument count: 0
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

   at WinRTBridge.MethodTools.InvokeMethod(Object instance, Int32 methodIndex, Object[] args)

(Filename:  Line: 65)
```

Comment: Well this doesn't say much. It would appear that an enumeration over some collection fails. You would need to give a little more background on what is causing these errors. For instance does this happen as soon as you run the game? Is there a particular action that you perform which throws these exceptions?

Comment: Rubens. Here is the flow of process when I get this error. First I made Unity build for Windows Store Apps. Then I took that build to Visual Studio Express for final build. Then run it on my device. After starting from splash screen to main menu screen all goes fine. As I hit play button to play the game, it throws this error. Whereas, this error does not come when I play the game in Unity interface.

Comment: can you try to put some check points to see where the exception is thrown. This will help pinpoint the issue.